# python にて「ImportError: cannot import name 'Presentation'」が発生する。

Tags: python, python3

pythonにてpptxをインストールして以下のサンプルを実行したところ

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Hello, World!"
subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!"

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\python\pptx.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pptx import Presentation
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\python\pptx.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pptx import Presentation
ImportError: cannot import name 'Presentation'
```

(base) C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads>`pip show python-pptx`
にて確認しましたがインストールはされているようです。

```
Name: python-pptx
Version: 0.6.9
Summary: Generate and manipulate Open XML PowerPoint (.pptx) files
Home-page: http://github.com/scanny/python-pptx
Author: Steve Canny
Author-email: python-pptx@googlegroups.com
License: The MIT License (MIT)
Location: c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: Pillow, lxml, XlsxWriter
```

フォルダも以下にありました。

```
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pptx
```

バージョンは
Python 3.6 version
python-pptx 0.6.9

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

もし実行しようとしているサンプルを `pptx.py` というファイル名で保存しているなら、それ以外の名前にして `Desktop\pyhon\` にある `pptpx.py` と `pptx.pyc` は削除してください。

`from pptx import Presentation` の `from pptx` が、そのサンプルコード自身を指しているためエラーになっているのだと思われます。

Answer (score 0):

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\python\pptx.py", line 1, in 
>   from pptx import Presentation
>   File "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\python\pptx.py", line 1, in 
>   from pptx import Presentation
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'Presentation'

というエラーメッセージですから、"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\python\pptx.py"に'Presentation'が含まれていないのでしょう。

"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\python\pptx.py"ではなく、インストールされている
”c:\users\XXXX\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\python-pptx”からインポートするように設定すれば解決すると思います。
（"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\python\pptx.py"というファイルを削除するだけで良いかもしれません）